# gtk 3 popup menu

Tags: python, menu, gtk

I am programming GTK 3.4 with python (with GObject introspection).
I don't understand why the menu created in the cb2 function does not show, or sometimes flashes and disappears, while clicking on bc1 works fine.

The program don't know all items to put on the menu before the user clicks the button.
Any ideas?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from gi.repository import Gtk

def create_menu():
    m = Gtk.Menu()
    item = Gtk.MenuItem(u"piano")
    m.append(item)
    m.show_all()
    return m

menu1 = create_menu()

def cb1(widget):
    menu1.popup(None, None, None, None, 0, 0)
    return True

def cb2(widget):
    menu2 = create_menu()
    menu2.popup(None, None, None, None, 0, 0)
    return True

w = Gtk.Window()
grid = Gtk.Grid()
w.add(grid)

b1 = Gtk.Button("cb1")
grid.add(b1)
b1.connect('clicked', cb1)

b2 = Gtk.Button("cb2")
grid.add(b2)
b2.connect('clicked', cb2)

w.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
w.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Do you get any errors or warnings when running the application in a terminal?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the python bindings

Don't create the menu within the callback, just populate it with items

```
m = Gtk.Menu()

def populate_menu(widget)
  item = Gtk.MenuItem(u"piano")
  m.append(item)
  m.show()
  return True


w = Gtk.Window()
grid = Gtk.Grid()
w.add(grid)

b1 = Gtk.Button("foofoo")
grid.add(b1)
b1.connect('clicked', populate_menu)
...
```